# How to repair permalinks on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache

I just relocated my wordpress application, and lost my permalinks.  I did NOT change URLs.  this is just a server-to-server transfer.  I'm hoping someone can see what I have done here, and tell me where I went wrong.

I'm expecting:  `https://trekfederation.com/%postname%` to work, but it fails.  When I turn off permalinks, Most of my links come back into play.  Woocommerce still is down, but I think that that particular issue is related.  To that end, I'm placing my .htaccess file and my apache2 virtualhost settings to see if someone can help me figure out where I went wrong.

Thanks

### .htaccess file

```
# Disable ETags
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset ETag
    Header set Connection keep-alive
</IfModule>
FileETag None

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css|css)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
# BEGIN DEFLATE COMPRESSION
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
# Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
</IfModule>
# END DEFLATE COMPRESSION
# BEGIN Cache-Control Headers
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
 <filesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
 Header set Cache-Control "public"
 </filesMatch>
 <filesMatch "\.(css)$">
 Header set Cache-Control "public"
 </filesMatch>
 <filesMatch "\.(js)$">
 Header set Cache-Control "private"
 </filesMatch>
 <filesMatch "\.(x?html?|php)$">
 Header set Cache-Control "private, must-revalidate"
 </filesMatch>
</ifModule>
# END Cache-Control Headers

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# NOTE this account's php is controlled via FPM and the vhost, this is a place holder.
# Do not edit. This next line is to support the cPanel php wrapper (php_cli).
# AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php70 .php .phtml
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# BEGIN cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
# Manual editing of this file may result in unexpected behavior.
# To make changes to this file, use the cPanel MultiPHP INI Editor (Home >> Software >> MultiPHP INI Editor)
# For more information, read our documentation (https://go.cpanel.net/EA4ModifyINI)
<IfModule php7_module>
   php_value zlib.output_compression off
</IfModule>
# END cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit

########### REDIRECT TRAFFIC TO HTTPS ############
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

############## CACHING-GZIP ############
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A2592000

<FilesMatch "\.(txt|xml|js)$">
ExpiresDefault A2592000
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(css)$">
ExpiresDefault A2592000
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(flv|ico|pdf|avi|mov|ppt|doc|mp3|wmv|wav|mp4|m4v|ogg|webm|aac)$">
ExpiresDefault A2592000
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|webp)$">
ExpiresDefault A2592000
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(txt|xml|js)$">
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
  </FilesMatch>

  <FilesMatch "\.(css)$">
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
  </FilesMatch>

  <FilesMatch "\.(flv|ico|pdf|avi|mov|ppt|doc|mp3|wmv|wav|mp4|m4v|ogg|webm|aac)$">
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
  </FilesMatch>

  <FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|webp)$">
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
# BEGIN WPSuperCache
# END WPSuperCache

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

### Virtual Host settings

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/vhosts/trekfederation.com"
ServerName trekfederation.com
<Directory "/var/www/vhosts/trekfederation.com">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What do you mean with lost permalinks? What is happening exactly?

Comment: all my pages with /%page-name%/ no longer work.  check it out https://trekfederation.com

Comment: Maybe mod_rewrite isn't enabled on that server?

Comment: That's what I thought, but when i run `sudo a2enmod rewrite`, it says `Module rewrite already enabled`

Answer (score 1):

WordPress saves its base url in the database in several fields. Have you checked that already? Most important is in `wp_options` the fields `siteurl` and `home`.

When you change the location (url) of your installation you can get problems with resources like styles and images not loaded and broken links.

You could change that via SQL with somethin like this:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE(meta_value, "https://trekfederation.com", "https://trekfederation.com/newlocation");

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, "https://trekfederation.com", "https://trekfederation.com/newlocation");

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = REPLACE (guid, "https://trekfederation.com", "https://trekfederation.com/newlocation");

UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = REPLACE(option_value, "https://trekfederation.com", "https://trekfederation.com/newlocation");
```

Comment: what happens if I'm not changing the URL?  is this still needed?

Comment: No if the url stays the same you don't have to do anything. You wrote you've relocated your installation so i thought the url have changed … Or what do you mean by relocating?

Comment: that's what I meant.  I moved servers.  and then changed DNS.  as far as the site is concerned...it's the same URL.

Comment: DNS take a while to refresh. Probably you don't get the right site?

Comment: I checked.   I adjusted an article using the database.  it shows different on the site (while I had permalinks off, I could view pages).

Comment: I figured it out.  It was a .conf apache file problem.

Answer (score 0):

ok.

I found out the problem.
I accidentally had TWO *.conf files for apache running this site.
I was updating ONE, wordpress was using the other.

Once I updated the OTHER one, it all came into play.